# How to remove part of string that includes special characters by RegEx or replaceAll?

Tags: java, regex

Here are the strings:

```
1. "AAA BBB  CCCCC CCCCCCC"
2. "  AAA              BBB  DDDD DDDD DDDDD"
3. "    EEE         FFF  GGGGG GGGGG"
```

The spaces at the beginning and between first and second word can vary.
So I need a RegEx to remove everything before third word so it always return
"CCCCC CCCCCCC" or "DDDD DDDD DDDDD" or "GGGGG GGGGG".
Assume it can be done by RegEx instead of parsing all words in the string

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yU4cS2/1

Comment: You can't just dump your requirements here and have your work done for you. Show your effort.

Comment: @rock321987 - post it as an answer. It's exactly what's asked

Comment: Doesn't make sense. What if you only have 2 words, does the string return empty. Anyway, just replace `^\s*(?:\S+(?:\s+|$)){2}` with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work

```
\s*\w+\s+\w+\s+(.+$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU4cS2/1)**

*JAVA Code*

```
String pattern  = "(?m)\\s*\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+(.+$)"; 
String line = "AAA BBB  CCCCC CCCCCCC\n  AAA              BBB  DDDD DDDD DDDDD\n    EEE         FFF  GGGGG GGGGG";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/XbeljB)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use group match to parse the required data

```
String result = null;

try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\w+\\s*\\w+\\s*([\\w| ]+)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("  AAA              BBB  DDDD DDDD DDDDD");
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        result = regexMatcher.group(1); // result = "DDDD DDDD DDDDD"
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Regex Explanation

```
"\\s" +           // Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   "*" +            // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"\\w" +           // Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores)
   "+" +            // Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"\\s" +           // Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   "*" +            // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"\\w" +           // Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores)
   "+" +            // Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"\\s" +           // Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   "*" +            // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"(" +            // Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   "[\\w| ]" +       // Match a single character present in the list below
                       // A word character (letters, digits, and underscores)
                       // One of the characters “| ”
      "+" +            // Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")"
```

Comment: I need also remove first and second words

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer from @rock321987 , you can modify the regex to use a quantifier to ignore any number of preceding words you don't want.

```
\s*(?:\w+\s+){2}(.+$)
```

[More info](https://regex101.com/r/yU4cS2/2)

Or in Java:

```
"\\s*(?:\\w+\\s+){2}(.+$)"
```

The ?: makes the pattern within the ( ) a non-capturing group.  The number within { } is how many words followed by spaces you want to ignore.